# Deleting Obsolete Windows 10 System Files on USB Drive

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-xp, usb, ntfs

I'm having trouble trying to wipe delete files from an obsolete Windows 10 To Go installation on a USB drive I have.  I've only been able to delete a fraction of the files so far, and have been blocked on the rest.  Access denied alerts and all.

I'm mostly using XP to try to do this (my sole user account), and would prefer it.

I'm trying to figure out what hidden NTFS file attributes there are, or where I'm being blocked permissions-wise.  There are some 60,000+ files.  So whatever solutions that will be able for me to practically do it for all them of them is what I'm looking for.

There are 600 GB of files on the drive that I want to keep.

Comment: why don't just format the drive?

Comment: Come on, homie.  Stick with the question at hand.  There are 600GB in files residing on the rest of the drive.  That's Y.

Comment: Have you tried running Explorer.exe as SYSTEM?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! If you want to keep other files on the drive (as you're implying), please **edit your question** to say so :)

Comment: System files may need elevated privileges to delete--at least administrator, maybe trusted installer.  Think about off-loading the stuff you want to keep, then reformatting.

Comment: The question at hand fails to indicate ANY information that makes it clear there are files you wish to protect. Rather than getting ruffled at a valid suggestion given the information, use the EDIT button to improve your question so that people will have ALL the information necessary to get you an answer.

Comment: OP, please see the answer provided by Tenent Jason for ample evidence why ALL pertinent information needs to be included in the question. @phuclv wasn't the only person who, reading your question, saw that formatting was the best way to solve the question you asked.

Answer (score 0):

The correct method is to take ownership of all of the files you wish to delete.

In Windows XP this requires starting in Safe Mode.

Navigate to the folder you need to delete, right-click, click Properties.

Select the Security tab, click Advanced, then open the Owner tab.

Select the correct entry from the list of possible owners, make sure to check **Replace owner on subcontainers and objects** and then click OK and follow any prompts.